# the exclamative 'what'

Tags: exclamations

The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language (Page 919):

> **8.1.2 Exclamative *what***
>
> *What* occurs in NPs with a following noun head: there is no exclamative counterpart to the interrogative *what* of *What did they bring with them?*

Does that mean the exclamative *what* can only be used with a following noun head?

If so, what about this example from [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/what)?

> (in exclamations) emphasizing something surprising or remarkable.
>
> ‘what some people do for a crust!’

Comment: 'Some people' is a NP following 'what'. Could you clarify what you are asking?

Comment: @Stefan In the Oxford example, 'some people' does follow 'what', but 'what some people' doesn't constitute an NP. Rather, 'what' is the object of 'do', and 'some people' is the subject. So, I don't think this particular exclamation is what the Cambridge Grammar is describing.

Comment: Note that a modern grammar does not describe when something _can_ be used (prescriptive), but rather when it _is_ used (descriptive).

Comment: There's a difference: exclamative "what" is an adjective in NPs, thus in "What a car that was!", "what" is modifying "car". But in "What some people do for a crust!", "what" is not an adjective modifying "people", but a pronoun serving as object of "do".

Comment: @BillJ So you agree that 'what' can be used as a pronoun in exclamation. Then, what do you think about the Cambridge Grammar's description of 'what'? According to the book, you can't say _What they brought with them!_ as exclamation. Why this doesn't work when _What some people do for a crust!_ does?

Comment: You're confusing exclamative clauses and exclamations.

Comment: @BillJ Terminology don't matter. I'm sure you understood my question.

Comment: It does matter. "What some people do for a crust" is an exclamation, but not an exclamative clause. This is the pronoun "what", not exclamative "what", which is an adjective. See what I mean?

Comment: @BillJ I'm not following you. Who says the exclamative 'what' has to be an adjective but never a pronoun?

Comment: H&P do.. It's an adjective serving as modifier in NP structure. It's all explained in CGEL.

Comment: @BillJ No, it's not clear whether CGEL says the exclamative 'what' cannot be a pronoun. And there's no syntactic evidence that the 'what' in the Oxford example is not the exclamative what.

Comment: Take a look at p435 [5], where it talks of **the adjectives "such" and exclamative "what"**. How much clearer can it be? In your example, "what some people" is not a constituent. The pronoun "what" is object of "do", i.e. it figures in clause structure.

Comment: @BillJ That doesn't tell you anything about whether the exclamative 'what' must always be an adjective. For example, "such" is an adjective in "such a disaster" but is not an adjective in "Such is life".

Comment: @BillJ And even if CGEL says so, that cannot be the reason for rejecting that the 'what' in 'what some people do for a crust!' is not the exclamative 'what'. It's entirely possible that CGEL's authers didn't think of this kind of example when they were writing the book.

Comment: Of course it does! "What" is a modifier, a dependent in the NP "What a disaster". If you don't like what H&P say, get a different textbook! And preferably read it more thoroughly than you have read CGEL!

Comment: @BillJ Note that CGEL fails to consider any example similar to Oxford's. And as much as I respect their work, CGEL is no perfect grammar, as I have pointed out several times in this site.